# Pattern Match Bug with Equals?

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to define a pattern matching function:

```
test[x__?MatchQ[Equal[_, _]]] := 1;
```

Now I give it a series of inputs, and expect each to output `1`:

```
test[1 == a, 1 == b]
test[1 == a, 1 == a]
test[1 == a, a == 1]
test[1 == a]
```

...none of which evaluate to `1`. I can't see what I've done wrong here. So I try the following:

```
MatchQ[Equal[_, _]][a == b]
```

Which gives `False`. I don't understand why. I look at the `FullForm` of `a==b` and it gives back `Equal[a,b]` which should match with the pattern `Equal[_,_]`.

However, for reasons beyond me, this expression...

```
MatchQ[Equal[_, __]][a == b]
```

...evaluates to `True`.

I have no idea what's going on here or why my `test` pattern match doesn't work. Can someone please explain what is going on? i.e.

- Why doesn't my `test` pattern match work as intended?
- How can I pattern match a sequence of equalities `a==b, c==d ...`?
- Why does `MatchQ[Equal[_,__]][a==b]` yield `True` while replacing `__` with `_` yields false?

Comment: A few things going on here. a) look at `Equal[_, _]`. It's `True`. So you'll need a `HoldPattern`. b) `?` is a high-precedence operator so you need `?(MatchQ[HoldPattern[Equal[_, _]]])`. Even better though would just be `x__Equal`. It's most concise and the fastest.

Comment: @b3m2a1 - Thanks! That pretty much answers it. Looks like *Mathematica* doesn't evaluate `_==__` so that explains the behaviour of that pattern match. You can write up a brief answer if you want.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer. I'm checking to see if this is a dupe (but a self-answer won't hurt either way).

Comment: You could also write `HoldPattern[_ == _] ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As *b3m2a1* answered in the comments, a couple of things were wrong with my code.

- `?` is a high-precedence operator, and so its argument should be encased in parentheses. i.e. `?(MatchQ[HoldPattern[Equal[_, _]]])` instead of `?MatchQ[HoldPattern[Equal[_, _]]]`
- *Mathematica* is evaluating `Equal[_,_]` to `True` before pattern matching! We need to use `HoldPattern[Equal[_,_]]`.

Comment: One more thing to add: `test[x__Equal] := 1` will work, too (and probably be faster)

Comment: @b3m2a1 - they have different behaviour, however. If the user enters `x==y==z`, I don't want this to be pattern matched.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. I assumed you were only working with `a==b` type expressions.